# Running several PdfTeX processes in parallel from within PdfTeX

Tags: shell-escape

I have a complex document setup where I have to produce several document versions. I want to start these runs in parallel to speed things up - and I want to control this from within PdfTeX. For this purpose I start these runs with a macro from within PdfTeX, as in

```
\immediate\write18{/Users/xyz/TEX/makeParallel \jobname \space  #1 \space }
```

This works nicely but produces a sequential execution, which is not what I want. So I tried

```
\immediate\write18{/Users/xyz/TEX/makeParallel \jobname \space  #1 \space & }
```

However, this leads to a truncated log file just in the middle of nowhere and a 2K byte PDF file which the PDF reader refuses to open.

Initially I had some suspicions that certain things have problems with reentering PdfTeX again while it is running. A candidate was `minted`, for example. So I made a complete duplication of all source files and the build directory to separate the instances. NOW, which means 30 hours later, I am starting to get a bit desparate. No matter what I do, sequential executions always work, parallelized versions consistently crash. I already tried all kinds of tricks, such as sending PdfTeX into the background in the shell script and not in `\write18` and other stuff. It is still the same. It looks like *some* process in my build chain (comprising `makeindex`, BibTeX etc) take offense in my idea and are not cleanly reentrant.

Any ideas what this could be?!?

**More details:** Commenters correctly point out that I am not giving enough information - which is due to the fact that I simply have tried out too many different variants which did not work.

Initially I did not use a script but started PdfTeX directly in `\immediate\write18` which did worked (but only when it was running in the foreground, i.e. without an & at the end). I then switched to the shell version as this makes it easier to change the commands and get them right  as - for me - the TeX escapements needed are less well known than shell.

The different runs do not share any files at all: The shell script first generates a complete copy of all files used in the tex run. In fact: `minted` and its cache system posed quite some problems so I decided to be that radical and just duplicate the **entire** environment.

I am running them from `write18` and not as parallel jobs at the end: I run this from TeXStudio and it is there that I preview and edit and make my checks. My use case requires to have all the other 6 versions ready by the time the TeXStudio foreground job has completed. So I have to start them early.

`\jobname` is the first shell parameter, which I need to access the correct filename in the copied environment. `#1` is the second shell parameter, which is filled in by a macro such as `\backJob{shortVersion}`. The shell script then uses this information to make a suitably named directory with all required source files and then start the PdfTeX run there. If I manually start the run: Everything is fine and no other files are touched afaik. If I start the script in the foreground: Just the same. If I start the tex run in the background (either by backgrounding the script or by backgrounding pdftex inside of the script): It breaks.

The must be **some** file which gets reused *somewhere*. Maybe some fancy `/tmp` or some `/hidden/somewhere/in/the/system` which I missed. But currently my brain seems to run out of suggestions here. I also tried `-recorder` as command line option to catch any overlapping files, but there is none.

What makes debugging even more problematic is the [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) nature of the phenomenon. Only when I run this from within `\write18` with shell backgrounding somewhere turned on does the problem show up.

Comment: You haven't really given enough information what is the script doing? Do the different runs share any file names (eg `\include ` files) also why run them from write18 you could just use the main tex run to generate a script that runs all the jobs in parallel at the end.

Comment: Are they all using `\jobname`?  I don't see how you're getting different commands.  And if you always have the same `\jobname`, then of course they're going to be writing to the same files and stepping on each others toes.

Comment: Also remember that if any of these documents share files that are being written to then this should not be run in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! :-)

The problem seems to be connected with the way `\immediate\write18` deals with output from the started process in the particular case of background activity.

`\immediate\write18{/Users/cap/TEX/makeParallel \jobname \space  #1 \space  > OUTPUT 2>ERROR &}`

works fine.

The problem shows up with
    `\immediate\write18{/Users/cap/TEX/makeParallel \jobname \space  #1 \space &}`

So far the therapy. Wrt diagnosis I suspect: The shell process wants to produce content on stdout and/or stderr and has no place to do so; as result of the backgrounding there is no reasonable terminal connection for this as well - and so somebody just decides to crash the process. This leads to the unpredictable end, corrupted pdf file, log file terminating in the middle of an output line etc.